# Как редактировать стороннее модальное окно?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, form

### Есть такое модальное окно:

```
<!-- www.123formbuilder.com script begins here --> <script  type="text/javascript" defer src="//www.123formbuilder.com/embed/5156508.js?type=lightbox" data-role="form" data-default-width="650px" data-embed-type="lightbox-text-link" data-embed-text-link="Получить"></script> <!-- www.123formbuilder.com script ends here -->
```

Оно выводит модальное окно, с заполнением имени, телефона, почты и ввода сообщения и кнопки отправить. Но оно было создано на сайте, и на нём есть реклама, задача убрать эту рекламу.
[image: Модальное окно]

Как убрать данную рекламу?

Answer (score 0):

Форма загружается через iframe. Повлиять на её стили и структуру Вы не можете. Вы бы могли переопределить `before`, `after` или блок с крестиком своими стилями, но на них стоят стили от формы через `!important`.

Очевидно, что нужно или менять сервис, где нет ничего лишнего, или писать свой.